# Is it possible to insert the specified value in autoincrement column?

Tags: sqlite

I need to copy one table to another and both tables contain column with `AUTOINCREMENT`. Is it possible to insert a defined value into `AUTOINCREMENT` column.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tmptimetables (
    _id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    _title NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    _weeks INTEGER NOT NULL,
    _first_week_date INTEGER NOT NULL,
    _auto_complete INTEGER NOT NULL,
    _first_lesson_time INTEGER NOT NULL,
    _lesson_duration INTEGER NOT NULL,
    _break_duration INTEGER NOT NULL,
    _color INTEGER NOT NULL,
    _symbol NCHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE timetables (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    weeks INTEGER NOT NULL,
    first_week_date INTEGER NOT NULL,
    auto_complete INTEGER NOT NULL,
    first_lesson_time INTEGER NOT NULL,
    lesson_duration INTEGER NOT NULL,
    break_duration INTEGER NOT NULL,
    color INTEGER NOT NULL,
    symbol NCHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
```

My SQL request:

```
INSERT INTO timetables (
    auto_complete, 
    break_duration, 
    color, 
    first_lesson_time, 
    first_week_date, id, 
    lesson_duration, 
    symbol, 
    title, 
    weeks
) 

SELECT 
    _auto_complete, 
    _break_duration, 
    _color, 
    _first_lesson_time, 
    _first_week_date, 
    _id, 
    _lesson_duration, 
    _symbol, 
    _title, 
    _weeks 
FROM tmptimetables
```

Comment: Yes, but it should be unique

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html - When you insert any other value into an AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to that value and the sequence is reset so that the next automatically generated value follows sequentially from the largest column value.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! I'm sorry I missed databases names but I got...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AUTOINCREMENT` can only be used for a column that is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, it is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY that is the factor that makes the column a special column whereby if the value is not provided when inserting a row that a unique integer will be assigned.

So be the column `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` you can specify an integer value and a row **may** be inserted with the given value.

**A row will not be inserted with a given value if that value is not unique.**

For example if the table **timetables** is currently :-

[image]

Then

```
INSERT INTO timetables (id,title,weeks,first_week_date,auto_complete,first_lesson_time,lesson_duration,break_duration,color,symbol) VALUES (null,'mytitle',78,86000,23,1800,900,200,16,'E');
```

Would insert a new row with the id as determined by SQLite's algorithm for providing a unique id (probably 5).

If the id were changed to be provided (i.e. not null) say to 10 as per :-

```
INSERT INTO timetables (id,title,weeks,first_week_date,auto_complete,first_lesson_time,lesson_duration,break_duration,color,symbol) VALUES (10,'mytitle',78,86000,23,1800,900,200,16,'E');
```

Then the id for the new row would be 10.

However if then using (the same SQL but with the last column value changed) :-

```
INSERT INTO timetables (id,title,weeks,first_week_date,auto_complete,first_lesson_time,lesson_duration,break_duration,color,symbol) VALUES (10,'mytitle',78,86000,23,1800,900,200,16,'Z');
```

A new row would not be inserted as a row with an id of 10 already exists.

Finally if the id is not given (null is used) but the SQL is otherwise the same a new row is inserted with a unique id being provided by SQLite e.g.

```
INSERT INTO timetables (id,title,weeks,first_week_date,auto_complete,first_lesson_time,lesson_duration,break_duration,color,symbol) VALUES (null,'mytitle',78,86000,23,1800,900,200,16,'Z');
```

So the end result of following the above is :-

[image]

---

#### AUTOINCREMENT

The `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword, only usable for an `INTEGER PRIMARY COLUMN`, invokes a different algorithm for determining the next sequence to ensure that the next sequence/id is always greater, whilst without `AUTOINCREMENT` a lower sequence/id can be applied.

The `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword does not specify that if a value for the column is not provided then a sequence/id is applied it is `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` that specifies that. Well actually, by default, i.e. unless `WITHOUT ROWID` is specified, this happens for all tables. It's just the the special **rowid** column is hidden. Specifying `<column_name> INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (where  is a valid column name) creates an alias of the **rowid**.

For example using `SELECT rowid,* FROM timetables` produces :-

[image]

- [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)
- [Rowid Tables](https://sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)